# catkin_make started failing to generate .h from .msg

Tags: ros, c++, catkin, jenkins, message-generation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a `C++` pkg that used to build successfully by `cakin_make`. But recently building starts to fail often, not always, with an error message:

```
~/catkinws_prv:$ rm -fR build/ devel/
~/catkinws_prv:$ catkin_make -j2
 :
~/catkinws_prv/src/rqt_common_plugins/rqt_marble/src/rqt_marble/bridge_ros_marble.cpp:39:33: fatal error: rqt_marble/RouteGps.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Scanning dependencies of target rqt_marble_gencpp
[ 55%] Generating C++ code from rqt_marble/RouteGps.msg
[ 55%] Built target rqt_marble_gencpp
Scanning dependencies of target rqt_marble_genlisp
[ 61%] Generating Lisp code from rqt_marble/RouteGps.msg
[ 61%] Built target rqt_marble_genlisp
Scanning dependencies of target rqt_marble_genpy
[ 66%] Generating Python from MSG rqt_marble/RouteGps
[ 72%] Generating Python msg __init__.py for rqt_marble
[ 72%] Built target rqt_marble_genpy
[ 77%] Building CXX object rqt_common_plugins/rqt_marble/CMakeFiles/rqt_marble.dir/include/rqt_marble/moc_bridge_ros_marble.cxx.o
The bug is not reproducible, so it is likely a hardware or OS problem.
make[2]: *** [rqt_common_plugins/rqt_marble/CMakeFiles/rqt_marble.dir/src/rqt_marble/bridge_ros_marble.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [rqt_common_plugins/rqt_marble/CMakeFiles/rqt_marble.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make" failed
```

Direct cause of the problem is clear: `RouteGps.h` is not generated from `RouteGps.msg`. But why?

System dependency should be correctly installed (as I said, `catkin_make` sometimes passes).

Because of this line in the error message above,

```
The bug is not reproducible, so it is likely a hardware or OS problem.
```

I thought my machine may have an issue, but as I cite later, the similar error occurs on `buildfarm`.

I first suspected my recent commits do something wrong, but even the commit that built well [like this initial commit](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/commit/e581d7714b49ca95b672f12e6b2a465f5439ffc6#rqt_marble) fails with the same error.

Anything wrong?

```
$ dpkg -p ros-groovy-catkin 
Version: 0.5.65-3quantal-20130325-0722-+0000
$ dpkg -p python-catkin-pkg
Version: 0.1.11-1
```

---

And although I'm not sure the correlation, `Jenkins` has also started [returning similar error](http://jenkins.willowgarage.com:8080/job/devel-groovy-rqt_common_plugins/ARCH_PARAM=amd64,UBUNTU_PARAM=precise,label=devel/4/console) (with my latest commit):

```
In file included from /tmp/test_repositories/src_repository/rqt_common_plugins/rqt_marble/include/rqt_marble/marble_plugin.h:42:0,
                 from /tmp/test_repositories/src_repository/rqt_common_plugins/rqt_marble/src/rqt_marble/marble_plugin.cpp:48:
/tmp/test_repositories/src_repository/rqt_common_plugins/rqt_marble/include/rqt_marble/bridge_ros_marble.h:12:33: fatal error: rqt_marble/RouteGps.h: No such file or directory
```

---

Update 5/7/2013) After adding `add_dependencies` I still saw the same issue. Eventually I moved a `.msg` file to another pkg and so far it builds nicely. [The link](http://answers.ros.org/question/52744/how-to-specify-dependencies-with-foo_msgs-catkin-packages/) that @Chad Rockey shared helped.

---

Update 5/14/13) Have been built fine locally, but `jenkins` has kept failing for the last 2 weeks, complaining the `.h` file from `.msg` is not found, although the console output implies it is built. I opened up a [new question](http://answers.ros.org/question/62707/jenkins-fails-to-generage-h-from-msg/) for this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62092/catkin_make-started-failing-to-generate-.h-from-.msg/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2013-05-03

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-05-07**:
Keeping all your messages in a separate package is a good idea, anyway.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-05-14**:
I can't discern your package dependency tree from the question. Perhaps there is a third intermediate package that also requires `add_dependencies()`?

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-05-14**:
@joq I've moved the latest update to [new question](http://answers.ros.org/question/62707/jenkins-fails-to-generage-h-from-msg/), and there we've found that I forgot to include a depended pkg in `find_package`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suspect you require an explicit dependency on the generated message targets, to ensure things always get built in the correct order:

```
add_dependencies(your_program ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
```

In your example maybe you just need this:

```
add_dependencies(your_program ${rqt_marble_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
```

**NOTE:** catkin compiles targets in parallel quite aggressively. The build machines tend to have more processors than most people's development systems. So, they may uncover missing dependencies that did not occur during development.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 12

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-05-06**:
Thx for an even clearer answer. I added `add_dependencies` and locally builds w/o error. Now I'm waiting for how `jenkins` handles it...

**Comment by [basheersubei](https://answers.ros.org/users/7676/basheersubei/) on 2014-08-12**:
I had a similar build fail and your line `add_dependencies(your_program ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})` solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What happens if you run catkin_make again for a second/third time without cleaning?  Does it complete the compile?

Sometimes you need to list it as a dependency, even though it's in another package:
http://answers.ros.org/question/52744/how-to-specify-dependencies-with-foo_msgs-catkin-packages/

---

Originally posted by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) with karma: 4541 on 2013-05-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-05-03**:
Yeah I've already found that re-running `catkin_make` generates the file I want...perfect WORKAROUND.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-05-07**:
I think @joq's answer should be the selected one, it is the correct way to fix this, running catkin_make multiple times is just suppressing or working around the actual problem.

**Comment by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) on 2013-05-07**:
If catkin_make succeeds on another pass, it is a good indicator that the fix I link to will work.  If it doesn't, there is another issue.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-05-07**:
As I've updated my OP, what's so far working for me (on local machine. I'm not yest sure about buildfarm since I'm still seeing a build failure on `jenkins`) is that link; having 2 pkgs where 1 pkg contains `.msg` on which the other pkg depends.